# Why are my aws starter account free credits getting used, when I didnt exceed the free tier limit?

Tags: amazon-web-services

[image: credits]I recently got the approval for the AWS educate account, and I started using it. I am a complete beginner at AWS and have only recently started learning it. I am using the free tier, yesterday I had created 2 lambda functions and 3 s3 empty buckets. The function didn't run and I got the access denied error, I dont know how to resolve that error, however when I logged into my AWS account in the morning I saw that some of my free credits had been used and the session time was three hours when I had only used it for 1 hour approximately, also I noticed that the session time is going up even when I am not doing anything but just logged into my account.[image]I must be unaware of something since I am very new to it. I would really appreciate if someone could help me figure this out.I am uploading the screenshots of the errors I had recieved.

Thank you[image: AWS-error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ignore it. It has nothing to do with billing.

It appears that the AWS Educate console is giving you **temporary credentials** to access the AWS account. These credentials are valid for a limited period. After **3 hours** you'll need a new set of credentials. Just go back to the console to get them. There is no cost associated with this, it's just the way they are granting access to the account.

It also appears that they are granting one year of access to the account. This has nothing to do with the Free Tier, it's just what the AWS Educate system is doing to give you the account.

A new AWS Account receives the [AWS Free Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/), which includes a certain amount of usage at no cost. In addition, the [AWS Educate](https://aws.amazon.com/education/awseducate/) account appears to include **$100 in credit** that will be used before you are personally charged for any services.

A certain amount of Amazon S3 and AWS Lambda is included in the Free Tier, so you probably haven't had any of the credits consumed yet. (Lambda is very low cost and you'll probably never pay for it. Similar for S3.)

**Bottom line:** Nothing to worry about. Not charged for anything.

As for the `Access Denied`, you will need to assign an IAM Role to the AWS Lambda function. That role needs to be given permission to use Amazon S3.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but they say that I will not be able to use the free tier once all the credits are used, I had 30 free credits, out of which 29.37 credits remain, although I had barely used it, I was just trying to figure. do you think any of my instance must be running?

Comment: Where are these "30 free credits" you mention? They are not shown in your screenshot. Could you please provide the exact wording?

Comment: You should be able to see your usage by going to the Billing Console (in one of the menus in the top-right) and clicking "Bill Details". However, it's possible that AWS Educate accounts might not grant you access to this information.

Comment: sorry about that, I must have missed it. I have edited my post to include the screenshot, thanks again.

Comment: and yes, you are right I cant access the bill details from my account

Comment: Ah! Yes, that is AWS Educate showing the remaining credits. Was it initially $30? If so, no big deal. Many of the services you will be using are part of the Free Usage Tier, which gets used before the credits.

Comment: yes it was $30 initially, thanks a lot for your replies, hoping to make the best use of the free tier while learning it. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215436/discussion-between-habiba-and-john-rotenstein).